# Martingale with same marginals constant?

Tags: probability

Assume that for two random variables $X,Y$ the relation E(Y|X)=X holds. Furthermore we know that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution. Is it then true that $X=Y$ a.s.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

If $X,Y$ are square integrable, then 
$$
E[(X-Y)^2] = E[X^2 - E[2X Y|X] + Y^2] = E[X^2 -2X^2 + Y^2] = E[Y^2]-E[X^2] = 0.
$$

---

Here is a solution in the general case.

Let for $a\in\mathbb R$   $f_a(x) = \max(x-a,0)$. Then by Jensen's inequality, $E[f_a(Y)|X]\ge f_a(X)$ a.s. But $E[E[f_a(Y)|X]]= E[f_a(Y)] = E[f_a(X)]$. Therefore, $E[f_a(Y)|X] = f_a(X)$ a.s.

Now let $g_N(x) = N(f_a(x) - f_{a-1/N}(x))$. Then $E[g_N(Y)|X] = g_N(X)$ a.s.
Letting $N\to\infty$, we get $E[\mathbf{1}_{Y\ge a}|X] = \mathbf{1}_{X\ge a}$ a.s. Multiplying by $\mathbf{1}_{X\ge a}$, $E[\mathbf{1}_{Y\ge a}\mathbf{1}_{X\ge a}|X] = \mathbf{1}_{X\ge a}$ a.s. Taking expectations, $P(Y\ge a,X\ge a) = P(X\ge a) = P(Y\ge a,X\ge a) + P(Y< a,X\ge a)$.

Thus, we get $P(Y<a,X\ge a) = 0$ for all $a\in\mathbb R$, whence the statement follows.

Comment: Thanks, would ne nice to know how the general case works ;)